# Need to know about Ubuntu PRO

Tags: 18.04, esm, ubuntu-pro

I have 18.04 LTS and I'm thinking of attaching the Ubuntu PRO token that I have received.
I would like to know if there are any caveats to it or will change anything in the VM if I attach the Ubuntu Pro subscription.
If it going to make changes to any applications, env, or repositories that I have
and is it safe to attach an Ubuntu PRO token using the command: sudo pro attach [YOUR_TOKEN]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has ended it's *standard* support life, thus isn't supported by the community now (*this is a community support site*). Ubuntu 18.04 does have ESM & Pro support options elsewhere, but SE only provides SE *Unix & Linux* now for EOL/EOSS releases.

Comment: Also take note to read the details; you'll quickly find not all architectures have ESM/Pro support (*your question is void of any of that detail anyway, so you may, or may not have an ESM/Pro option*).  Key is read the details  (*I've been aware of ~6 people who've followed advice on this site & not considered the architecture details, thus why I mentioned it; discovering it only when they get the 'unsupported architecture' answer to the command you provided*)

Comment: I have already checked that but there's no info about it if we update to Ubuntu Pro - will it change my repositories, app, packages, env, etc..
And If I attach the Ubuntu pro token and then detach it- will it cause any issues or make any changes?

And I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 architechture.

Comment: There are numerous blogs about Ubuntu Pro, even the FAQ (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042)

Comment: Your non-Pro 18.04 system has already been missing security updates for almost four months. Those ended 31 May 2023.

Comment: Whether or not attaching your Pro token to your VM is safe or not is between you and Canonical. Pro is a proprietary service owned by them. We have no special insight into their service, we are not Canonical employees, and we are not Pro Customer Service. Nobody has reported here that their use of Pro has caused major changes to their system, and most people here think Pro is "safe"...but you are the one responsible for doing your own research.